# Background Task to Fetch HealthKit Data

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, background-task

I am using iOS 13 where Background Task framework there. My Query is

1. Can it will be possible to fetch HealthKit Data in Background Mode.
2. Can i send these Healthkit data to My server using Post request using backbround mode.
   Please help me out and provide your guidelines .

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to fetch data in background mode. You must run a HKObserverQuery and enable background deliveries.

HKObserverQuery docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobserverquery/executing_observer_queries

Enabling background deliveries docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614175-enablebackgrounddelivery